# Terraform detects changes when there isn't any

Tags: terraform

I'm using terraform v1.1.3, whenever I run `terraform plan` it states I have made changes even when nothing at all has changed locally or remotely. For example, if I run `terraform apply` then `terraform plan` immediately after, it states that objects have changed outside of Terraform and forces replacement of my instance.

```
  # module.database.oci_core_instance.instance[0] has changed
  ~ resource "oci_core_instance" "minstance" {
      + extended_metadata                   = {}
        id                                  = "ocid1.instance.oc1.me-jeddah-1.anvgkljrnghkmsacizo3ubuejydotfi7qz45if32x2e3b55mhirvrvpiw7nq"
```

Why?

```
resource "oci_core_instance" "instance" {
  availability_domain                = random_shuffle.compute_ad.result[count.index % length(random_shuffle.compute_ad.result)]
  compartment_id                      = var.compartment_id
  shape                               = var.instance_shape
  freeform_tags                       = var.freeform_tags 
  shape_config {
        memory_in_gbs = 16 
        ocpus         = 1  
    }
  source_details {
    source_type = "image"
    source_id   = lookup(data.oci_core_images.compute_images.images[0], "id") 
   
  }
  metadata = { 
      ssh_authorized_keys = file(var.ssh_public_key) 
      user_data           = data.template_cloudinit_config.nodes.rendered
  }
  count = var.num_nodes

  depends_on = [
    oci_core_volume.volume_1
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably because the data resources blocks aren't evaluated until the apply, during the plan it does not know what is in

```
 data.template_cloudinit_config.nodes.rendered
```

so to be safe, it marks it as changes

If you are 1000% sure that this is not something that will ever change, you could add

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
        extended_metadata
    ]
  }
```

But be very careful with this, as if the metadata does change in future, it will simply not apply.

Comment: That makes sense, anyway I can change this behaviour?

Comment: I updated my post to reflect an answer to your comment

Comment: to add another example. Say you created resource in Azure that can be tagged in the same block in terraform but you do not do it, but e.g. you have a Policy that adds tags to every new created resource. Next apply you will see that it will be marked as "changed" just because tags were added and this could be done with this particular terraform resource type also. lifecycle/ignore_changes proposed by @DarkMukke is a correct solution for you

Answer (score 2):

I think what you see here is a minor bug in the OCI provider. I think that in the underlying remote API there is no difference between this argument being unset or it being set to an empty map, and so when the provider reads the latest state of the object during the refreshing step it doesn't distinguish between those situations and so it overwrites the `null` (representing it not being set at all) with an empty map.

If that's true then without modifying the provider I think you could avoid this only by writing the configuration in a way that matches what the provider will produce when it refreshes the object, by including an explicit empty map for that argument:

```
  extended_metadata = {}
```

The refresh step will then find the same thing that was saved during the initial creation of the object and so won't produce this errant change report.

The "real" fix here would be for the provider to treat `null` and `{}` as equivalent values for this argument, and to so not report a change from `null` to `{}`, but that may be hard for the provider developers to achieve depending on how this argument is currently implemented.